# Binding и string concatenation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть два свойства edgeType и id. Их нужно вывести в одну строку через пробел.
Как это сделать?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding edgeType id}" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте MultiBinding и StringFormat.

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>    
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
            <Binding Path="edgeType" />
            <Binding Path="id" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте фрагменты, например:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Id}"/>
    <Run Text="{Binding EdgeType}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Преимущество фрагментов в том, что вы можете устанавливать для них разное форматирование, например:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Id}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Run Text="{Binding EdgeType}" FontSize="16"/>
</TextBlock>
```